# How to get the custom payload from pyapns using phonegap push plugin?

Tags: django, cordova, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-pushplugin, pyapns

we are using [PYAPNS](https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs) to send push notifications from an Django application to iOS devices running an phonegap application.

The server code looks like this:

```
def sendNotificationAPNS(title, message, targets, eventid):
    apns = APNs(use_sandbox=False, cert_file='/path/to/push_cert.pem', key_file='/path/to/push_cert.pem')

        # Send a notification
        for token_hex in targets:
            payload = Payload(alert=message, sound="default", badge=1, custom={'eventid':str(eventid)})
            apns.gateway_server.send_notification(token_hex, payload)
            print('Notification to APNS send!')

        return true
```

On the mobile application the code from Phonegap Push Plugin looks like this:

```
// handle APNS notifications for iOS
function onNotificationAPN(e) {
    if (e.alert) {
        console.log('APNS Notifiation recieved: ' +  e.alert);
        // showing an alert also requires the org.apache.cordova.dialogs plugin
        navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
    }

    if (e.sound) {
        // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
        var snd = new Media(e.sound);
        snd.play();
    }

    if (e.badge) {
        pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
    }
    //eventid
    if(e.eventid) {
        console.log('APNS eventid: ' + e.eventid);
    }

    //custom
    if(e.custom) {
        console.log('APNS eventid: ' + e.custom.eventid);
    }
}
```

The problem is: I don't get anything for e.custom or e.eventid?!
What do I have to change to access the custom payload?

Thanks!